# Threading a task beside a GUI PyQT4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, qthread

So i am trying to run a PyQT GUI while another functions is gathering information in the background. If Information is found the GUI should update itself.

I am new in Threading so i googled a lot and found some good HowTo's although it does not work as it should.

when i run the program it just ends itself after 3 s.

Maybe you see some major mistake ive done.

Here is the basic code i am trying to get to run

```
class scan_Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, samp_rate, band, speed, ppm, gain, args, prn):
        QThread.__init__(self)
            self.samp_rate=samp_rate
            self.band=band
            self.speed=speed
            self.ppm=ppm
            self.gain=gain
            self.args=args
            self.prn=prn

        def __del__(self):
            self.wait()

        def run(self):
            do_scan(self.samp_rate, self.band, self.speed,
                    self.ppm, self.gain, self.args, self.prn)


def start_gui():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    #app.exec_()
    #sys.exit()

def main(options = None):

    def printfunc(found_list):
        for info in sorted(found_list):
            print info

    get_thread = scan_Thread(options.samp_rate, options.band, options.speed,
                options.ppm, options.gain, options.args, printfunc)
    get_thread.start()
    start_gui()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the objects of the Qt classes and therefore of PyQt need to start some object of type Application (QCoreApplication, QtGuiApplication or QApplication), but only one of these objects must exist.

In your particular case QThread needs it. The previous classes are responsible for generating the necessary loops.

So you should modify your code to the following:

```
def main(options = None):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) // before creating any PyQt object.

    def printfunc(found_list):
        for info in sorted(found_list):
            print info

    get_thread = scan_Thread(options.samp_rate, options.band, options.speed,
                options.ppm, options.gain, options.args, printfunc)
    get_thread.start()
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey, that worked. Thanks a lot! Another problem i am facing right now is that when the scan_Thread finds some addition information i would like to restart the GUI but the GUI stucks in app.exec() and i cannot acces it from the scan_Thread. Any Ideas?

Comment: Restart the GUI or update the view of the GUI ?, any of them should not be done from a secondary thread, create a signal in the secondary thread and connect it to a slot in the GUI and in it you must do the task necessary to update the gui.

Comment: Restart the GUI would be the easiest, all new information would then be displayed. I trying to get into signals but my brain seems incapable to.

Comment: @Crubuntu There is no GUI restoration, just update the elements of the GUI, you must use signals. If you have problems with the signals I could help if you share your code through github, drive or similar.

Comment: https://github.com/Knoedelchan/GrGsm-Gui/tree/Cridibranch the file is grgsm_scanner. The Idea is, always when "do_scan" finds a new channel and appends it to the output file to update the GUI to show the new channels. If you have some ideas i would be grateful.

Comment: what is grgsm module?

Comment: With GrGsm u can use an RTLSDR Stick to sniff GSM signals. It is from here https://github.com/ptrkrysik/gr-gsm and uses gnuradio.